Which port is used through OC CLI in Openshift?
I need to ask for firewall rule to access to openshift via OC CLI. I guess destination will be worker nodes IPs. Which port I need to open?

By default openshift uses 6443 port and for ui or https it uses 443. You can try to whitelist for port 6443
OC CLI will talk to Openshift API (API Server), which is running in Master. So Communication happens in such a way Client talks to API Server and based on the request (C- Create, R - Read, U - Update , D - Delete) API Server will take up with other control plane components
